# How to listen to internet explorer close event in gwt land

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I want to listen to internet explorer close event in gwt land. Is that possible? Would it be different for IE-7 and IE-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Window.ClosingHandler.
The Window.ClosingEvent will be fired just before the browser window closes or navigates to a different site.

Comment: The problem i have now is that after the window closes ,the event is getting fired.I want to fire the event before window closes . I am basically trying to achieve a confirmation on close

Comment: Then use the `Window.ClosingEvent` and [setMessage](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html#setMessage(java.lang.String)) on it to get the confirmation from the browser, using this message.